# Are RX Java objects in android bound to an activity?

Tags: java, android, reactive-programming

Are react components bound to the calling activity's lifecycle(like asynctasks)? How do they persist on a more serious configuration change e.g. when a network provider is switched?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rx Java is not bound to an activity, that's the one of the main advantage.
You need to handle manually the subscription and unsubscription in different scenarios, one example would be when acivity is being destroyed.

Read more about it on the Rx documentation.

Comment: So it's like a service with an observer implementation.